# Export declaration or expression expected in React components. Difference between Export method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I having a react component. code as below

```
import React from 'react';
export const Header=()=>{

        return(
            <div>this test</div>
        );
}
```

This work properly fine.

However if i use below code it gives me error, Export declaration or expression expected.

```
import React from 'react';
const Header=()=>{

        return(
            <div>this test</div>
        );
 }

export  Header;
```

Can some one explain the differences between these two export.
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want named export you need

```
export  { Header };
```

or

```
export  { Header as Smth };
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

> export { name1, name2, …, nameN };
>
> export { variable1 as name1, variable2 as name2, …, nameN };
>
> export let name1, name2, …, nameN; // also var, function
>
> export let name1 = …, name2 = …, …, nameN; // also var, const

`export name` is just invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
export default Header
```

to make second one work. 
Then, you can import it from another file by

```
import Header from './Header'
```

or even

```
import InsertAnythingHere from './Header'
```

given that relative path of file is `./Header.js`.